# Week difference from current week to last day previous week

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a pivot pandas data frame (sales by region) that got created from another pandas data frame (sales by store) using the pivot_table method.

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'store':['A','B','C','D','E']*7, 
     'region':['NW','NW','SW','NE','NE']*7, 
     'date':['2017-03-30']*5+['2017-04-05']*5+['2017-04-07']*5+['2017-04-12']*5+['2017-04-13']*5+['2017-04-17']*5+['2017-04-20']*5,
     'sales':[30,1,133,9,1,30,3,135,9,11,30,1,140,15,15,25,10,137,9,3,29,10,137,9,11,30,19,145,20,10,30,8,141,25,25]
     })
df_sales = df.pivot_table(index = ['region'], columns = ['date'], aggfunc = [np.sum], margins = True)
df_sales = df_sales.ix[:,range(0, df_sales.shape[1]-1)]
```

My goal is to do the following to the sales data frame.

Add a column called week difference that computes the difference between the total sales for this week, and the latest value (by date) for the previous week. Assumption: I always have data for some days a week but it's not fixed days.
The week difference column will be different as new data comes in, but for the latest data would look like:

```
>>> df_sales
              sum                                                         \
            sales                                                          
date   2017-03-30 2017-04-05 2017-04-07 2017-04-12 2017-04-13 2017-04-17   
region                                                                     
NE           10.0       20.0       30.0       12.0       20.0       30.0   
NW           31.0       33.0       31.0       35.0       39.0       49.0   
SW          133.0      135.0      140.0      137.0      137.0      145.0   
All         174.0      188.0      201.0      184.0      196.0      224.0   



date   2017-04-20 WeekDifference 
region             
NE           50.0    50.0-20.0
NW           38.0    38.0-39.0
SW          141.0    141.0-137.0
All         229.0    229-196.0
```

Because it's the difference between the latest date and the latest day of the previous week. In this specific example, we are on week 2017-04-20, and the last day of data from previous week is 2017-04-13.

I'd want to do this in a general way as data gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'store':['A','B','C','D','E']*7, 
     'region':['NW','NW','SW','NE','NE']*7, 
     'date':['2017-03-30']*5+['2017-04-05']*5+['2017-04-07']*5+['2017-04-12']*5+['2017-04-13']*5+['2017-04-17']*5+['2017-04-20']*5,
     'sales':[30,1,133,9,1,30,3,135,9,11,30,1,140,15,15,25,10,137,9,3,29,10,137,9,11,30,19,145,20,10,30,8,141,25,25]
     })
df_sales = df.pivot_table(index = ['region'], columns = ['date'], aggfunc = [np.sum], margins = True)
df_sales = df_sales.ix[:,range(0, df_sales.shape[1]-1)]
```

Input:

```
              sum                                                         \
            sales                                                          
date   2017-03-30 2017-04-05 2017-04-07 2017-04-12 2017-04-13 2017-04-17   
region                                                                     
NE           10.0       20.0       30.0       12.0       20.0       30.0   
NW           31.0       33.0       31.0       35.0       39.0       49.0   
SW          133.0      135.0      140.0      137.0      137.0      145.0   
All         174.0      188.0      201.0      184.0      196.0      224.0   



date   2017-04-20  weekdiffernce  
region                            
NE           50.0    50.0 - 20.0  
NW           38.0    38.0 - 39.0  
SW          141.0  141.0 - 137.0  
All         229.0  229.0 - 196.0
```

Calculate Last week and one week offset:

```
last_column = pd.to_datetime(df_sales.iloc[:,-1].name[2])
```

<strike>last_week_column = last_column + pd.DateOffset(weeks=-1)</strike>

```
col_mask = (pd.to_datetime(df_sales.columns.get_level_values(2)).weekofyear == (last_column.weekofyear-1))
```

<strike>df_sales.loc[:,('sum','sales','weekdiffernce')]=df_sales.iloc[:,-1].astype(str) + ' - '+df_sales.loc[:,('sum','sales',last_week_column.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))].astype(str)</strike>

```
df_sales.loc[:,('sum','sales','weekdiffernce')]=df_sales.iloc[:,-1].astype(str) + ' - '+df_sales.loc[:,('sum','sales',list(col_mask))].iloc[:,-1].astype(str)

print(df_sales)
```

Output:

```
              sum                                                         \
            sales                                                          
date   2017-03-30 2017-04-05 2017-04-07 2017-04-12 2017-04-13 2017-04-17   
region                                                                     
NE           10.0       20.0       30.0       12.0       20.0       30.0   
NW           31.0       33.0       31.0       35.0       39.0       49.0   
SW          133.0      135.0      140.0      137.0      137.0      145.0   
All         174.0      188.0      201.0      184.0      196.0      224.0   



date   2017-04-20  weekdiffernce  
region                            
NE           50.0    50.0 - 20.0  
NW           38.0    38.0 - 39.0  
SW          141.0  141.0 - 137.0  
All         229.0  229.0 - 196.0
```

Comment: thanks.  This answer assumes that we always have data for a 1-week lag, but in my question i mentioned that for some days i have data and for others i don't.  That is why i need the last day of the previous week.  Would you mind pointing me in how to generalize this answer to that edge case?

Comment: Get the previous records 1-week or more? Is there an edge case where you have only a day within 1 week?

Comment: i want the behavior to be such that it compares against the last day of the previous week.  For example if the latest data was on 2017-04-17 the week difference would be the difference between the sales in 2017-04-17 and 2017-04-13.  And your code would instead compare 2017-04-17 and 2017-04-10, which doesn't exist in the data